# count table rows based on another table id

Tags: mysql, select, count

I'm trying to count my rows based on another table id

DRIVER DB TABLE

```
agent_id  driver_id   driver_name
--------  ----------  -----------
2         1           AAA
2         2           BBB
2         3           CCC
1         4           DDD
```

I want to show the result (how many drivers are there based on `agent_id`). For example agent_id 2 have 3 drivers agent_id 1 have 1 drivers. How to do that?

Comment: What are you missing? is learn ["aggregate functions"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) with ["group by"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need this:

```
  SELECT agent_id, COUNT(driver_id) AS `drivers`
  FROM driver
  GROUP BY agent_id
```

output like:

```
--------+---------+
agent_id|drivers  |
--------+---------+
1       |   1     |
2       |   3     |
--------+---------+
```

## [click the sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/752e80/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
  count(driver_id) as `drivers`,
  agent_id
  from driver
  group by agent_id
```